# Rollback a Webdeploy publish in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-migrations, webdeploy

I have Web Deploy setup with code first migrations executed on publish for an MVC project. Is there a way to rollback a publish if I screw something up? I can write unit and integration tests until I am blue in the face but inevitably some bug or error will get through. It would be much better to rollback changes than try and fix an error while the live site is down. I also have a ruby on rails project that I normally deploy using Capistrano. It has a handy "cap deploy:rollback" command which I use regularly. I need something like that for my MVC project.

Comment: I'm actually looking for the same functionality. I can create a tag from source control but it's just another step in the deployment routine. The whole point of publishing direct from VS is to reduce steps :)

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is create specific branches and tags in your source control then deploy off of those tags. If you want to deploy a previous version just checkout that branch/tag and deploy that.

You can also specifically run a migration using this script.

```
Update-Database -TargetMigration:0
```

Just modify your deploy script to specifically call the latest version of your migrations that is on that branch.

Taking these few steps will allow you to just deploy that branch/tag you want and your production environment will always be in sync.

Note: The only caveat is whether your migrations can be destructive.